# related rates, actor and camera

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the camera is fixed at $(0,0)$ and the actor is at $(x,y)$ (initial value of the position). Assume further that the rate of change of $x$ is $u$ feet per second and the rate of change of $y$ is $v$ feet per second. Find the formula for $tan(θ)$, and use implicit differentiation to find a formula for the rate of change of $θ$. Let $θ$ be the angle between the positive $x$ direction and the line of sight from the camera to the actor as a function of $t$.

I supposed that $tan(θ)=y/x$, but system marked my answer as a wrong one. What $tan(θ)$ is then? I'm confused.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $y,x$ are the initial values not the actual coordinates of the actor at any instant

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: Let θ be the angle between the positive x direction and the line of sight from the camera to the actor as a function of t.

Comment: using $x,y$ as initial coordinates might have confused you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a,b)$ denote the coordinates of the actor at any time $t$:

So, from the problem we have:

Rate of change of $a$ is $u$ feet per second $\rightarrow \frac{da}{dt} = u$

Similarly for the rate of change of $b$ that is $v$ feet per second $\rightarrow \frac{db}{dt} = v$

So:

$$
\left\{ \frac { da }{ dt } \quad =\quad u\\ \frac { db }{ dt } \quad =\quad v \right\} \\ \left\{ a\quad =\quad \int { u\quad dt } \\ b\quad =\quad \int { v } dt \right\} \\ \left\{ a\quad =\quad ut+c\\ b\quad =\quad vt+c' \right\} 
$$

And using our initial conditions:$a(0) = x, b(0) = y$ we get:

$$c = x, \quad c' = y$$

Finally we get:

$$
\left\{ a\quad =\quad ut+x\\ b\quad =\quad vt+y \right\} 
$$

Here's the part where you did the mistake:

$$\tan{(\theta)} = \frac{b}{a}\qquad ({1}^{*}) \\
\tan { (\theta )\quad =\quad \frac { vt+y }{ ut+x }  } 
$$

Now let's move on to $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$:

We will differntiate $\tan{(\theta)}$ instead and rearrange to get $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$:

$$
\tan { (\theta )\quad =\quad \frac { vt+y }{ ut+x }  } \\ \frac { d }{ dt } \left( \tan { (\theta ) }  \right) \quad =\quad \frac { d }{ dt } \left( \frac { vt+y }{ ut+x }  \right) \\ \frac { d\theta  }{ dt } (\tan { (\theta )') } \quad =\quad \frac { vx-uy }{ { (ut+x) }^{ 2 } } \\ \frac { d\theta  }{ dt } \left( 1+\tan ^{ 2 }{ (\theta ) }  \right) \quad =\quad \frac { vx-uy }{ { (ut+x) }^{ 2 } } \\ \frac { d\theta  }{ dt } \quad =\quad \frac { vx-uy }{ { (ut+x) }^{ 2 } } \times \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ \left( \frac { vt+y }{ ut+x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\\frac { d\theta  }{ dt } \quad =\quad \frac { vx-uy }{ { (ut+x) }^{ 2 }+{ (vt+y) }^{ 2 } } 
$$

Notes:

- ${(1)}^{*}$ instead of using the coordinates at any instant you calculated it for $x,y$ which are the initial coordinates at $t=0$